# UINavigationController issue - if i return to first view, i see the color of second view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am creating UINavigationController and it's UIViewControllers like this. First with yellow color, second with blue color.

Then adding it to stack. Yellow is displayed for a while, then the second blue.

What's the problem - if i press the button in top bar to get back to previous Controller, i don't see yellow background but blue, thought the title of window is "One" which is correct.

Why is this happening? Thx

```
UIViewController *one = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[one.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[one setTitle:@"One"];


UIViewController *two = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[two.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[two setTitle:@"Two"];


UINavigationController * navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:navController.view];
[navController pushViewController:one animated:YES];
[navController pushViewController:two animated:YES];
```

Comment: In which class you writing this code?

Comment: probably in some UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what's the reason.

Because navController was relased from the memory.